# How to get value from Model > NSDictionary and parse to another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a ViewController A and retrieve JSON data in ViewDidLoad by using following method:-

```
[self.manager GET:@"http://api.sampleWebsite.com/api/xx" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        json_product = responseObject;
        self.aryProducts=[NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *subDic in json_product) { 
            ProductItem_Model *model=[[ProductItem_Model alloc]initWithDic:subDic];
            [self.aryProducts addObject:model];
        }

            [self.collectionView reloadData];

    }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
              }];
}
```

**Model.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface ProductItem_Model : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString <Optional>*name;

- (instancetype)initWithDic:(NSDictionary *)dicProductItem;

@end
```

It will working fine and return result in **Model.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithDic:(NSDictionary *)dicProductItem{
    NSError *error = nil;
    self =  [self initWithDictionary:dicProductItem error:&error];
    NSLog(@"CORRECT RESULT WILL RETURN HERE%@",dicProductItem);
    return self;
}
```

In my **ViewController B**, how can I pass in NSDictionary list from Model as mentioned above? Here is my sample code:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *gridcell = nil;

     ProductItem_Model *model = [[ProductItem_Model alloc]init];
     NSDictionary *subDic;
     NSLog(@"HOW CAN I PASS IN THE NSDICTIONARY LIST HERE - %@",[model initWithDic:[subDic objectForKey:@"name"]]);
```

Comment: `ProductItem_Model *model = [self.aryProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; NSDictionary *subdict = [model propertyYouWantThatStoreTheDictionary]`? But clearly, parse the whole dictionary with properties for each of its values.

Comment: Hi @Larme, sorry for my stupid question, what can I put in "propertyYouWantThatStoreTheDictionary"?

Comment: @henry How are viewControllers A & B connected? Are they connected via segue on Storyboard, or do you instantiate B from A? Or are they not linked at all?

Comment: @JimTierney, no linked at all, only will share the same data. Possible to make it?